# The function 'return'( C ) do not appear when running the code in Powershell (Windows 11)

Tags: c, return

I'm trying to create a function thet has to return an integer and even though my program does not have any error, nothing appear when running the code in PowerShell. Here is an example. Does anybody know why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRhpP.png)

Is it maybe some sort of console's configuration setting that I should change ?

Comment: The return parameter from `main` (as a process entrypoint) is interpreted as the exit code of the process, which PowerShell then writes back to [a special variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4#lastexitcode) - check `$LASTEXITCODE` immediately after running the program.

Comment: That picture does not show "running the code in PowerShell".  At a guess, you're running the compiled program in WSL, at the Bash shell prompt.  There are other possibilities, but PowerShell is not one of them.

Comment: In any case, C `return` does not mean "print to the screen" or anything like that, not even in the initial call to `main()`.

Comment: There does not seem to be anything related to `PowerShell` in this question. If so, the `PowerShell` tag should be removed.

Comment: Good points, @JohnBollinger, but note that it is definitely possible to install PowerShell (Core) in WSL (though I agree that the screenshot suggests Bash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by some comments, `return` in C does not output anything to the console. It simply returns the value 1 from the function `main`.

The integer returned from `main` signals the [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the program. You can check it by entering the following into your terminal after running the program:

```bash
# In POSIX shell:
echo $?

# In PowerShell:
echo $LASTEXITCODE
```

To have the program write something to the terminal, you can use the `printf` function from the C Standard Library.

```c
#include <stdio.h> // Include the standard "io" library

int main()
{
    // The standard programmer greeting :)
    printf("Hello, world!\n");

    // Or, if you want to write an integer
    printf("%d\n", 1); // "%d" is a format specifier

    return 0; // 0 exit code means "OK"
}
```